# why is $\mu(D) > 0$ where $D=\{ x \in X : ||f||_\infty -\epsilon < |f| \}$

Tags: real-analysis

why is $\mu(D) > 0$ where $D=\{ x \in X : ||f||_\infty -\epsilon < |f| \}$

I know this should be strait forward with the fact that $||f||_\infty$ is the supremum norm but I am having trouble working out the details

Comment: No, $||f||_\infty$ is _not_ the supremum norm! If you get straight _exactly_ what the definition of $||f||_\infty$ actually _is_ the answer to your question should become clear...

Answer (score 1):

Because by definition $\|f\|_\infty$ is the infimum of all numbers $\alpha$ such that $\|f\|<\alpha$ almost everywhere. So, for any $\varepsilon>0$ the set of points such that $\|f\|>\|f\|_\infty-\varepsilon$ has positive measure.